# jquery jtable - customizing the table title

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Looking to jtable.org sample code, I see the table title can be redefined and in all samples there is a "+Add New Record" button.

I am interested in replacing this button by a dropdown list (to set a couple of actions) plus a "Go" buton to actually perform the chosen ction.

How this could be accomplished?

Of course I know how to  code this widget pair on top of the the table and below, but I wanted to take advantage of the screen space used by the jtable title.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-toolbar) api reference. May be this will help you. Here you can handle click functionality of toolbar. Following is code reference taken from Jtable.org-

```
toolbar: {
    items: [{
        icon: '/images/excel.png',
        text: 'Export to Excel',
        click: function () {
            //perform your custom job...
        }
    },{
        icon: '/images/pdf.png',
        text: 'Export to Pdf',
        click: function () {
            //perform your custom job...
        }
    }]
},
```

Comment: The answer from "abpatil" is exactly what I was looking for, however it is not working and I verified it is an oppen issue based on comments from gitHub.